# How to Turn an Integer Into Separate R,G,B Colors

Tags: colors, integer, rgb, equation

I have been attempting to solve this for a while now, basically I want an integer, such as white (16777215) to be converted back into RGB (255,255,255), but I have no idea how.

I know R+(G*256)+(B*65536) = Integer but I want Integer = R,G,B.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int R = (i & 0x000000FF);
int G = (i & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
int B = (i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
int A = (i & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
```